# AM/PM DateFormat substitution at TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, datetimepicker, date-format

I have some layout/button and **onClick** I get **TimePickerDialog** with current time (previously defined from **Calendar**):

```
    RelativeLayout time = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.time_layout);
    time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            TimePickerDialog dateDialog = new TimePickerDialog(SelectDateTimeActivity.this,
                    TimeSetListener,
                    hours, minutes, false);
            dateDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

**TimePicker** is in **12h mode** - it has **AM/PM** mark. **TimeSetListener** looks like

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener TimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        hours = hourOfDay;
        minutes = minute;
        updateTimeRow();
    }
};
```

and **updateTimeRow()** is

```
private void updateTimeRow() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

    timeBody.setText("@ " + (String) (DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa", c.getTime())));
}
```

The problem is that time set in TimePickerDialog **06:00 PM** (which really is 18:00, I checked via logging) I get **06:00 AM** in my timeBody textView. If I set it to **06:00 AM** (which really is 06:00) in timeBody textView I get **06:00 PM**. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HOUR_OF_DAY in place of HOUR.

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
```

Replace it with:

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
```